# Using an array as a hash key in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Hello stackers i am debugging my first ruby app that implements a simple bank (withdraw, deposit, transfer, etc). I need to ask the user for their card number then compare it to a hash to get the person associated with that card. I can't seem to get the value though it seems i am comparing an identical array to the hash key.

```
def addAccount(person,card,key,account)
        @key = "Kudzu"
        if(key === @key)
            $people[card["card_number"]] = person
            $accounts[card["card_number"]] = account
            return true
        else
            puts "Access Denied: atm.addAccount"
            return false
        end
    end



    def start_trans()
        while(true)
            STDOUT.flush
            puts "Insert Card (1234 5678 9123 4567) >> "
            temp = gets.chomp
            @card = temp.split(" ")
            puts @card 
            puts @card.class
            puts $people
            @person = $people[@card]
            if(@person)
                @account = $accounts[@card]
                get_pin()
                break
            else
                puts "Didn't catch that try again" 
            end 
        end
    end
```

My Output:

```
Insert Card (1234 5678 9123 4567) >>
6327 6944 9964 1048
6327
6944
9964
1048
Array

{[6327, 6944, 9964, 1048]=>#<Person:0x2ae5548 @zip="12345", @cash="123", @name="r", @card={"card_number"=>[6327, 6944, 9964, 1048], "exp_month"=>11, "
exp_year"=>2018, "security_code"=>468, "zip_code"=>"12345", "pin"=>"1234"}, @account=#<Account:0x2ae5530 @person=#<Person:0x2ae5548 ...>, @atm=#<Atm:0
x2ae5500>, @name="r", @balance=nil, @accounts=nil, @key="Kudzu", @pin="1234", @card={"card_number"=>[6327, 6944, 9964, 1048], "exp_month"=>11, "exp_ye
ar"=>2018, "security_code"=>468, "zip_code"=>"12345", "pin"=>"1234"}>>}

Didn't catch that try again
Insert Card (1234 5678 9123 4567) >>
```

I added a empty line to my output on here before and after i puts $people just for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your `$people` hash defined as

```
$people = {["6327", "6944", "9964", "1048"] => blabla... }
```

you'll get the following output for `puts $people`:

```
{["6327", "6944", "9964", "1048"] => blabla... }
```

From the output you posted, it seems that you stored the card number as **array of number** for the `$people` hash key. However, you then tried to query the associated value with **array of string**, which definitely wouldn't work.

You need to convert the input into array of number before you query the associated data:

```
puts "Insert Card (1234 5678 9123 4567) >> "
temp = gets.chomp
@card = temp.split(" ").map(&:to_i)
....
```

Generally, it's bad practice to use `Array` as hash key in Ruby, because the `Array` it mutable, which may cause inconsistency between the key and key hash code. I would consider using `Symbol` for the card number:

```
# update people
$people_updated = Hash[ $people.map{|k, v| [k.join.to_sym, v]} ]

# query
puts "Insert Card (1234 5678 9123 4567) >> "
temp = gets.chomp
@card = temp.scan(/\d+/).join.to_sym
...
```

Comment: @Ane Shaw Thanks just realized this by putting my input into a hash and displaying it (I didn't think of trying this before posting unfortunately). Deleting my answer and accepting yours. Thanks for being awesome.